# Refresh button after saving data in visualforce

Tags: visualforce

### How to create a refresh button on my visualforce page

```
public PageReference save(){
        try{
            upsert orgInfo;
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'Created successfully'));
        }
        catch(System.DMLException e){
              ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,''));
            return null;
        }
        orgInfo = null;
        ScheduledOrgInfoFetch.ScheduledOrgInfoFetch();
        return null;        
    }
```

Updated :

     
       
          
              Org Information
          
       
    
        
          
            
               
                
                            Client ID: 
                            Client Secret: 
                            Username: 
                            Password: 
 
                            Sandbox?

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Can you add little bit more information about your use case so that members can give you proper direction. And what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have added my comment on how to refresh the form after save, please check your earlier Question.

Comment: the code in on the above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the refreshed view after an update, You can achieve it as follows:-

if you are trying to get refreshed view in classic mode:-

```
       public PageReference save(){
            try{
                 upsert orgInfo;
                 if(UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed()=='Theme3' ){
                 ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'Created successfully'));
                 PageReference pr = new PageReference('/' +orgInfo.id);
                 pr.setRedirect(true);
                 return pr;  
                }else{
                return null;
            } 
            catch(System.DMLException e){
                  ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,''));
                return null;
            }
        }
```

This should give you a refreshed view in Classic mode. Many a time pagereference does not give you a refreshed view in Lightning, hence just I keep pagereference limited to classic view.

For Lightning what you all need is:-

In your visualforce page, you need to include below code:-

```
<script>
    function  refresh(){
    sforce.one.back(true);
        }
</script>
```

And render your save button for Lightning separately. the first button will render in classic i.e theme 3 and the second one will render in Lightning i.e theme 4d.

```
<apex:commandbutton value="Save" action="{!saveRecord}" rendered="{!$User.UITheme == 'Theme3'}"/>
    <apex:commandbutton value="Save" action="{!saveRecord}" oncomplete="return refresh();" rendered="{!$User.UITheme == 'Theme4d'}"/>
```

Comment: it's not working.. the data are still there. further explanation please

Comment: Can you once change the method name and try?? Or try to post your vf page required snippet too.

Comment: i follow the codes that you give but there's an error. the error was "The Apex job named "Client Info" is already scheduled for execution."

Comment: I.e because in finally block, you are calling the schedulable class to schedule a job. Once it is scheduled already, maybe that's why it is giving you an error. Is it necessary to call a schedulable  class and schedule a job every time a record gets updated? Can you tell me more about your functionality?

Comment: yeah, your right are we going to catch that error?

Comment: Then write it in the try block, the error will be get caught in catch block

Comment: how would I do that sir? I'm new in this programming languages

Comment: @jan can you tell me what exactly you are trying to achieve. You have asked about refreshing the page, that I have made clear to you. But as you are also scheduling a job, its hard to answer without knowing the full functionality of your code.

Comment: The code starts when the user inputs an data on text field then click save it will automatically set a schedule, the point is after I did save the data that is input is still their, that's all the functionally of my code

Answer (score 0):

You can use render attribute of action for particular element where your upsert property is reffered it will automatically update new changes on UI.